# Searchbar to search across all external html pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a website and it needs a search functionality. The website has a bunch of html pages example: index.html, about.html, contact.html etc etc ... The search bar is in the nav of every page, i want to be able to type something in on the index.html page and if there is a result in the about.html page show that result. Now i don't have a problem doing a search on the page i am on at the moment but i don't even know where to start to be able to search "external html pages" example about.html. I have search and browsed the internet cant find anything. Can you do this in Jquery or javascript?

Any help or advise will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: If it is possible at all??

Comment: I think you need to create a "datastore" to index the content. It is possible to solve your problem but it is really bad in term of network since we need to fetch each page repeatedly.

Comment: you can do something like this to show google search results

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript's Ajax call to get all the pages that you have and use regex to look for stuff that you are looking for.

Here is the example
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/client-side-web-scraping-with-javascript-using-jquery-and-regex-5b57a271cb86

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>             
 $.get('https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/', function(response) {                    
  var query=(response.search(/Using CORS - HTML5 Rocks/i));
  if(query>-1){
    console.log("https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/")
  }
  else{
    console.log("not found")
  }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would recommend to use database of some sort for this kind of stuff

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this to implement google search

```
site:lifewire.com power search tricks
```

see how [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com) has implemented their search box
This can be a approach. Since google searches their keywords accross every single page on web. 
You can use their feature and mould it according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this piece of code for this:

**IMPORTANT:** Do **NOT** use this script in bottom of your `<body>`, instead write this in `<head>` tag. If you write this in `<body>` you always get current page as one of the search founds.

```
    var myPages = ["About.html", "Index.html", "Store.html"]; //your pages in here
    var searchResult = []; //here we have result
    var searchFor = "chicken soup"; //what we search

    $.each(myPages, function (index, value) {

        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: 'GET',
            url: value,
            success: function (data) {

                var body = $(data).text().replace(/\s+/gm, ' ');

                if (body.indexOf(searchFor) >= 0) {
                    searchResult.push(value);
                }

            }
        });

        if (index + 1 == myPages.length) {
                alert(searchResult);
        }

    });
```

I strongly have the opinion that you should **NOT** do this. Because its really slow. Imagine you have 50 pages, client should wait for search in 50 pages. Instead as *Wisnu* suggested fetch details from a datastore or an index page or from a database....

Comment: Thanks for this i will try it out !